# Where to get JavaFx JNI symbol files (pdb files) for windows

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-8

My JVM is crashing when running a JavaFx media application on windows when internal C program calls into JNI without any exception stack or message. My JDK version is 8u121. Where can I find it's symbol files or pdb files to debug the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The standard image does not include these symbols. However if you build the JavaFX sources yourself you can generate the symbol files with it.

How to build JavaFX sources can be found at [building OpenJFX](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX).